# SpriteKit simulation speed / applyImpluse speed

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode, skshapenode, skphysicsworld

I'm in the process of learning sprite kit and decided a catapult style game would be a good project to start with.

I am launching a projectile by using `physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: strength * dx, dy: strength * dy))` and this all works fine.

I'm currently trying to predict the trajectory of the projectile. I am doing this by applying the same impulse to a hidden SKNode and plotting the path it takes.

The problem is that the user has to wait until the impulse/physics has finished until they can see the full path. (see image below)

[Path Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fnpg.gif)

[image]

(from the image above) I want the green path to either appear instantly or appear a lot faster.

I've tried to adjust the speed of the SKNode but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the simulation (it always runs at the same speed). I've also tried using `SKAction.applyImpulse` with the speed property being adjusted but it didn't have any effect either.

The only thing that has worked is setting `physicsWorld.speed` but I don't want to change the speed of the whole physics world, only the hidden trajectory node.

I was wondering if there was a way to run the physics simulation on a specific node instantly, or at least speed it up so it runs quicker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No that's the physics world that controls whole the simulation. Nodes are not autonomous, they are all in the same physics world. You may stop everyover node, set the speed of physicis world to a greater value, let the node run and at the end reset the simulation speed to its original value?

Comment: Thanks Jean, I could try that although it seems a little bit hacky?

Comment: Yes but the other choice is to implement the physics calculation to compute the path. Afterall, spritekit uses standard Newtonian physics. I've been unable to found it but someone asked for it some weeks ago...

Comment: Perhaps the physics calculation would be the best option. I will look into it, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can massively increase the gravity, and then factor this increase into the increase in the force used to project your object. This will result in the same arc of flight, but rising and falling much faster.